# How to get the first 10 characters of a string and then format them as date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have the following data on a google sheet:

| test_date |
| --- |
| 2022-07-21 19:02:29.788000+00:00 |
| 2022-07-20 01:43:35.598000+00:00 |

What I want to do is to get the date only and the format it to a new column something like this:

| test_date | clean_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-21 19:02:29.788000+00:00 | 7/21/2022 |
| 2022-07-20 01:43:35.598000+00:00 | 7/20/2022 |

I have done the following code for the apps scripts extension that google sheet has, however I have the ongoing issue that only one date is set up on the column and it's not format as date:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const r = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,1);
  var v = r.getValues();
  const result = v.map(row => row[0].substring(0,10))
  //const valueL4D = r.substring(0,10)
  r.offset(0,2).setValues(result)
}
```

Any guidance on this?

Comment: Are you looking for just a script or a formula alternative as well?

Comment: just for a script, the formula I already have the formula but the request is to be done in apps scripts, I know it's more complex

Answer (score 1):

#### get the date

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const v = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  const result = v.map(e => [Utilities.formatDate(new Date(e),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy")]);
  sh.getRange(2,2,v.length,v[0].length).setValues(v)
}
```

Comment: That should work fine and probably even autocoerces the text strings to dates in spreadsheets whose locale by default uses `mm/dd/yyyy`. But it will fail on other spreadsheets. Use `yyyy-MM-dd` to fix that. Also dates close to midnight will not be correct because by default `Session.getScriptTimeZone()` gets `UTC`. Use `ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()` to fix that.

Comment: Are you missing square brackets `[]` here?  `[Utilities.formatDate(new Date(e),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy")]);`

Answer (score 1):

Since they're strings(and not dates), use regex with [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
v.map(row => [row[0].replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}).*/g, '$2/$3/$1')])
```

- `\d` digit
- `{n}` number of digits
- `${n}` replacement groups for each capture group `()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Date` constructor, like this:

```
  const result = v.map(row => row.map(value => new Date(String(value).substring(0, 10))));
```

Note that timezone offsets may come into play in the event your spreadsheet and script projects use a different timezone setting.

But it would probably be a lot easier to do the same with a spreadsheet formula, like this:

`=arrayformula(to_date(value(left(A2:A, 10))))`

To format the result, use **Format > Number > Custom date and time**.

Comment: ok this does the trick, however it's substracting a day from the original date, so if I have 7/21/2022 it converts it to 7/20/2022

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant when I noted that that timezone offsets may come into play in the event your spreadsheet and script projects use a different timezone setting. Use a spreadsheet formula to always get it right. Alternatively, use @Cooper's solution with the fixes outlined in the comments.